# Highlighting a search term in a query?

Tags: php, sql, highlighting

I'm having trouble highlighting a search term within a query. If a user searches "Jesus", all verses that contain "Jesus" will be listed and paginated. I want to highlight the search query in all of these passages.

Let's say I search for "Jesus", and some 10 verses pop up, I want all instances of Jesus on every page to be highlighted.

My PHP code:

index: http://pastebin.com/vTdy79er
bible database: http://www.mediafire.com/?00x4fnbn1vr4nch

I have no idea how to go about doing this.

my select statement for my queries:

```
$searchResult = $dbLink->prepare("SELECT   bsect, bname, bnum, cnum, vnum, vtext,                                             MATCH    (bname, vtext)
AGAINST  ('$searchQuery' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AS       relevance
FROM     kjv
WHERE    MATCH (bname, vtext)
AGAINST  ('$searchQuery' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY relevance
DESC
$limit");
```

The code that actually displays my results (bible name chapter number : verse number and then verse text:

```
while ($searchResult->fetch())
{
print ("<span class=\"results title\">$bname $cnum:$vnum</span>");
print ("<p class=\"passage\">$vtext</p>");
}
```

Comment: Reduce your code sample to a RELEVANT subset. We're not going to read that wall of code to tell you how to do this. Show what you've attempted so far, and we can help fix that.

Comment: It's just a bunch of select statements and looping, nothing really relevant. It takes a few fields from the database and displays them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you already do it here:

```
$output = str_replace($_GET[phrase],"<font color=red>" . $_GET[phrase] . "</font>",$output);
```

even if I would suggest to change the code like this:

```
$output = str_replace($_GET['phrase'],'<font color="red">'.$_GET['phrase'].'</font>',$output);
```

or even better, use a `<span>` tag and a class, and then assign all the CSS that you want to that class and make it easier to change in the future

**EDIT/ADD**

with your last updated message, this is what you have to do (if I understand your code correctly)

```
print ("<p class=\"passage\">$vtext</p>");
```

change it to (assuming that `$searchQuery` is the variable that contain that string that is searched for

```
echo '<p class="passage">'.(str_replace($searchQuery, '<font color="red">'.$searchQuery.'</font>', $vtext).'</p>';
```

I also like better echo than print, but is personal preference.  For sure you want to avoid the `"` and use the `'` when possible as it will speed up PHP as the engine will not have to parse the whole string to find variables.. but again, personal preference

Comment: I actually just copy pasted that from another site, had no idea what I was doing lol.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

jQuery [SearchHighlight](http://www.jquery.info/spip.php?article50) plugin. Demo and implementation are provided.

Comment: This looks great, will give it a shot soon.

Answer (score 0):

I did not look at your code but something like this should work:

```
echo str_replace($searchWord, '<span class="highlight">' . $searchWord . '</span>', $row['verse']);
```